# Highcharts Pie Chart Label Threshold

Tags: highcharts

Is there a preferred way to eliminate or aggregate labels below a certain threshold when using HighCharts pie chart? I'd rather not have to rollup all values below a certain percentage into 'other' if I can. I've checked the docs and can't find anything. It would be very useful!

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I know this is a long time later, but added an answer to solve your issue below.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to achieve this is to use dataLabels formatter for pie chart like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function(){
                if (this.percentage < SOME_VALUE) return "";

                return VALUE_TO_SHOW;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Replace `SOME_VALUE` and `VALUE_TOSHOW` with desired values. But there will be some problems if you're using connector for you labels (it is always visible).

Comment: Ah, so if we return null there is no hanging line? I assumed there would be, and just no label at the end. Will give this a try.

Comment: i've tried several values (null, undefined..) but line didn't become invisible

Comment: Me too. If only we could set connectorWidth to 0 in the formatter function we'd be good. I might just go with connectorWidth to 0 for now plus your suggestion, it looks a bit better than lots of small values overlapping.

Comment: @IgorDymov null appears to have the correct behavior in the newest version of Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/FKawc/2/

Answer (score 2):

A *very* late answer to this question:

If instead of returning empty string, you instead return null, the label AND connector will not show, and you'll be able to achieve this effect without removing the connector:

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FKawc/2/)

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function(){
                if (this.percentage < SOME_VALUE) return null;

                return VALUE_TO_SHOW;
            }
        }
    }
}
```